# How can I get a list of filepaths from the project assets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have added a bunch of Images to my App's resources folder and I want to list all of the Images from my icons folder, so the user can pick which one they want to use for their listelement.

My Folder is included in the Pubspec.yaml and I can call AssetImage("/res/assets/icons/") and it gets the image I want manually.

I want to store the path later to call AssetImage(path) on it.

But when I call `List files = Directory("/res/assets/icons/").listSync();`, I get this exception:

[image: Exception]

What do I need to do to get all the file paths from the files in my directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Flutter 3**, you can retrieve a list of all the images in a specific directory like this:

```
final images = json.decode(await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json')).keys
    .where((String key) => key.contains('assets/icons/'))
    .toList();
print(images.toString());
```

For older Flutter versions, you can achieve the same result using:

```
final images = json.decode(await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json')).keys
    .where((String key) => key.contains('res/assets/icons/'))
    .toList();
print(images.toString());
```

Remember to replace `'assets/icons/'` or `'res/assets/icons/'` with the actual path you want to target.

Comment: This no longer seems to work in Flutter 3

Comment: it works in flutter 3 just use 'assets/icons/' instead of 'res/assets/icons/' also make sure the files are added in pubspec.yaml